# Get the given date format (the string specifying the format) in javascript or momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, format, momentjs

Given a datestring, how can I get the format string describing that datestring?

Put another way, how can I get the format string that Date() or MomentJS (might be different for each, that's fine) would use to parse that datestring if one didn't pass an explicit format to use?

So given `'2016-01-01'` it should output something like `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, for example.

(I am aware this is a simple question and may have an answer somewhere, but it is difficult to word concisely, so I could only find questions and answers about how to parse datestrings or how to display dates. None about how to output the *format* itself.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consolidating information from [Matt Johnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37735700/3391108), some comments, and my own contribution.

With Moment.js (version 2.10.7+), you can use the [Creation Data API](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/). Something like this in Node.js:

```
moment('2016-01-01 00:00:00').creationData().format
```

outputs

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
```

Just as any date parsing is, there is ambiguity about the format of many datestrings due to things such as locale (the order of months and days are switched between the US and Europe, for example). But the above method is sufficient for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, without having additional information, such as the *locale*.  For example, `01/12/16` could be Jan 12, 2016, December 1, 2016, or December 16, 2001.

Even when you know the locale, there are several places in the real world where more than one date format is used, depending on context.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

However, if you are just trying to determine which one of multiple known formats was used to parse the input string, moment has an API for that called [Creation Data](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/).  For example:

```
var m = moment("2016/06/10", ["YYYY-MM-DD", "MM/DD/YYYY"], true);
var f = m.creationData().format;  // "MM/DD/YYYY"
```

Comment: Sure, but one of the multiple options must be able to be chosen given that they can parse these strings. So, yes, there's an ambiguity, but a choice can be made, and is implicitly made already since parsers exist.

Comment: I think *format* is a better term here than *locale* since the location of the source and destination systems likely doesn't help much. ;-)

Comment: @tscizzle—without the format you're just guessing. While some formats have a higher chance of "success" than others, strings like 03/04/05 can be parsed to produce at least 3 valid, but different, dates. See [*Be careful when falling back to Date constructor*](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407) (which probably should be *…falling back to Date.parse*).

Comment: @tscizzle - see my updated answer - perhaps that will help you.

Comment: it DID help, thanks! but just so you know, it does indeed work as i wanted originally :) i.e. you don't have to pass it the multiple known formats. this works perfectly: `moment('2016-01-01 00:00:00').creationData().format`. it outputs `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: Yes, but be careful.  That only works if your input is in one of the supported formats [listed here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).  If you pass anything else, it will fall back to the `Date` object's constructor internally, you'll get a warning message in the debug console, and you'll find that `creationData().format` returns `undefined`.  See also http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/