# Get locale format with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to recover the date format according to the location. For example, if I use `moment.locale('fr')` retrieve `"DD/MM/YYYY"` or retrieve `"YYYY/MM/DD"` with `moment.locale('en')`. 
As you can see, I use MomentJS for my date management.

Is there a MomentJS function to recover the format?

Comment: If I have understood your issue, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15994039/5254433) can resolve it.

Comment: see also [Get the given date format (the string specifying the format) in javascript or momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37735700/1176601)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I was looking for was:

`moment().creationData().locale._longDateFormat.L`

I found the answer thanks to Aprillion. Thanks!

Comment: You can access it in a way that you don't read private variables: moment().creationData().locale.longDateFormat('L');

Answer (score 31):

```
moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L') // "MM/DD/YYYY"
```

and

```
moment.localeData('fr').longDateFormat('L') // "DD/MM/YYYY"
```

seems better

Comment: in new moment js slash is replaced with point

 "MM/DD/YYYY" =>  "MM.DD.YYYY"

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, I get a more sophisticated way to solve this problem, just with:

```
moment().format('L')
```

Instead of this verbose solution with eslint warning:

```
moment().creationData().locale._longDateFormat.L
```

Comment: I am not getting it with first solution, only second works. (First gives me, eg: "10.09.2019", second gives me "DD.MM.YYYY").

Answer (score 1):

```
moment().creationData().locale.longDateFormat('L');
```

> // MM/DD/YYYY

working code from [Rui Marques](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085483/rui-marques)