# Javascript Date Parse with specific locale

Tags: javascript, datetime, locale

I receive date/time objects from user input, and would like to parse them to a javascript Date object. The date is in the format: `02/06/2018 00:59:03` which means second of june, 2018; UK locale.
Although this seems extremely trivial and a super wide use case scenario, I can't seem to find anything in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) how to specify the locale I wish to use for parsing.

What the parser does is simply assume I am using US locale format, which defaults to having first the month, then the day, and then the year, so it mixes up month and day.

Currently the only available option I see is writing my own parser, which is fine ish (it is not, of course, as I might tomorrow need another locale), but seems a little 1980ies to me.

Maybe I overlooked something in the documentation. But does anyone have any other solution? Would be greatly appreciated.

P.s. I can hardly imagine this has not been asked yet, but my search did not turn up much either.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From MDN's [Date() documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and
> Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to
> browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format
> strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in
> that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not
> local.

If your input is structured and the format is constant, writing your own parser should be straightforward.  Here's an approach using a regular expression.

```js
var dateString = '02/06/2018 00:59:03';

var dateParser = /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
var match = dateString.match(dateParser);
var date = new Date(
    match[3],  // year
    match[2]-1,  // monthIndex
    match[1],  // day
    match[4],  // hours
    match[5],  // minutes
    match[6]  //seconds
);

console.log('Input: ' + dateString);
console.log('Output (en-US): ' + date.toLocaleString('en-US'));
console.log('Output (en-GB): ' + date.toLocaleString('en-GB'));
```

Alternatively, string splitting would be pretty easy as well (i.e. split by a space, then split the first result by `/` and the second result by `:`).

Comment: Thanks @chuckx for the accurate answer (although not what I hoped); plus the parser included. I would think that these days, with javascript so advanced, one would expect to have reverse functions for things like toLocaleString() as well.

Comment: My answer applies when you're sticking to vanilla JS. However, as @Andreas mentioned, momentjs is a library which addresses your concern.  Specifically, see [the parsing functionality where you can specify the input format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: Yes, I failed to mention that I was looking for a vanilla solution, otherwise I would jump immediately to using a library.

Comment: xor: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53211160/529663. It returns the formatting string for dates in a locale.

Comment: And in typescript, you need to use this syntax to avoid errors: `parseInt(match![3]),  // year` etc.