# Convert a AM/PM date string to JavaScript date using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-format

I have a date string like this `20/09/2018 12:00 AM`. I need to stop to put the previous date than today. I have searched the web for it, but no answer found with this format.

I need the default date format of JavaScript so that I can compare with new Date() value. When I use the following format it show the message that says `invalid date` because of my `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt` format.

```
alert(new Date("20/09/2018 12:00 AM"));
```

Comment: Why "using jquery"?  This has nothing to do with dom manipulation.  This is purely a logical problem.

Comment: i need to use this in script. to check the date is not from previous. I am having the value from input field and need to cust to javascript date object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Date Parse with specific locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781887/javascript-date-parse-with-specific-locale)

Comment: javascript != jquery. One is a language, the other a framework. There is no need to use jquery here.

Comment: I recommend you try to solve this using [*moment.js*](https://momentjs.com/), you can specify the format when parsing a date/time string and there are plenty of convenience functions like `isAfter` and `isBefore`

Comment: I was about to mention _moment.js_ also. You can do this: `var m = moment("20/09/2018 3:14 PM", "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a"); m.toDate();`

Comment: @StephenP can you add this as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Igor recommended using *moment.js* to solve this — it is a widely used date/time library.

With moment.js you can do this:

```
var m = moment("20/09/2018 3:14 PM", "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a");
var d = m.toDate();
```

The first line creates a "moment" object by parsing the date according to the format string specified as the second argument. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

The second line gets the native javascript `Date` object that the moment object encapsulates; however, moment can do so many things you may not need to get back that native object.

See the [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Your format isn't valid, thus you're getting `invalid date` error. So, using your format(dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt) we'll grab the year, month, day, hours and the minutes, then we'll reformat it as an acceptable format by the `Date` constructor and create a `Date` instance.

Here's a function that do all what being said and returns a `Date` instance which you can compare it with another `Date` instance:

```js
function convertToDate(str) {
  // replace '/' with '-'
  str = str.replace(/\//ig, '-');
  
  /**
  * extracting the year, month, day, hours and minutes.
  * the month, day and hours can be 1 or 2 digits(the leading zero is optional).
  * i.e: '4/3/2022 2:18 AM' is the same as '04/03/2022 02:18 AM' => Notice the absence of the leading zero.
  **/
  var y = /\-([\d]{4})/.exec(str)[1],
      m = /\-([\d]{2}|[\d])/.exec(str)[1],
      d = /([\d]{2}|[\d])\-/.exec(str)[1],
      H = /\s([\d]{2}|[\d]):/.exec(str)[1],
      i = /:([\d]{2})/.exec(str)[1],
      AMorPM = /(AM|PM)/.exec(str)[1];
  
  // return a Date instance.
  return new Date(y + '-' + m + '-' + d + ' ' + H + ':' + i + ' ' + AMorPM)
}

// testing...
var str1 = '20/09/2018 12:00 AM';
var str2 = '8/2/2018 9:00 PM'; // leading zero is omitted.
console.log(convertToDate(str1));
console.log(convertToDate(str2));
```

> The `Date` depends on the user's/server's location, two users may have
>   different results.
>
> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date)
>   about `Date`.

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Both examples are returning null when I run the code snippet