# How can we get the moment format of date-time string ? (if the date-time string is available.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have the following date-time string `25/10/2020 10:12:55 AM`. Is there any available method that I can use to get it's format?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the given date format (the string specifying the format) in javascript or momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733966/get-the-given-date-format-the-string-specifying-the-format-in-javascript-or-mo)

Answer (score 0):

According docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/  you can use the following

```
moment().creationData().format
```

More about this feature request here https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4595

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this you can add the `parseFormat` plugin using the following command: `npm install moment-parseformat`.  Using this you should be able to do the following:

```
var format = moment.parseFormat('25/10/2020 10:12:55 AM');
```

`format` should have the date format string that you are looking for.  Check out this link(https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/parseformat/) for more information. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the format from creationData as long as you pass it something in a valid RFC2822 or ISO format:

`moment('2020-10-25T10:12:55').creationData().format` returns `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`